# join to fetch users who do not have a busy date--the available users

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join two tables `User` and `Busy Days`. I want to fetch all the users who do not have a busy date--the available users.

User

| user_id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Doe |

Busy Days

| id | busy_date | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-26 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-05-26 | 2 |
| 3 | 2022-05-29 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-06-01 | 2 |

I want to search by date. If 2022-05-26 the result should be zero because both users have a busy day on that date, but if 2022-05-27 both users should appear.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select username from user
 where id not in (select user_id from busy_days where busy_date = "2022-05-26")
```

Comment: Yes, it works, is it ok to achieve this without joining?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me with `not exists`.

```sql
select U.USER_ID
  from USER U
 where not exists (select 1
                     from BUSY_DAYS B
                    where B.USER_ID = U.USER_ID
                      and B.BUSY_DATE = 'some date')
```

Note: Replace `some date` with your actual date, e.g. `2022-05-26`.
Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5791c942d1daf771732a49086b06f6a6)

Answer (score -1):

***For joining two tables***

`SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN Busy_Days ON User.user_id=Busy_Days.user_id;`

***Then to achieve the result***

`SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN Busy_Days ON User.user_id=Busy_Days.user_id WHERE NOT Busy_date=2022-05-27;`

`SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN Busy_Days ON User.user_id=Busy_Days.user_id WHERE NOT Busy_date=2022-05-26;`

> Hope this helps you if you have any query regarding this please feel
> free comment

Comment: Please do not use * in such queries, please provide aliases, please do not use columns without providing the table name or better the table alias. This is all very risky. Also not ... = ... is bad style, just use ... != ...

Comment: Furthermore, this query will produce results for the 26th May, but the OP doesn't want a result in this case.

Comment: No, it doesn't work...